# How does Apache find /var/www

Tags: 14.04, apache2, configuration

Sometimes you run into a problem when you know you will be embarrassed when you hear the solution.

I have a very simple setup of `Apache` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and deleted everything from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, restarted apache, and still it serves `index.html` from `/var/www/html/`

My question:

how is this possible? 
Which config file makes this happen?

I inspected `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, ran

```
grep -i DocumentRoot *
```

in `/etc/apache2` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, and did not solve my problem.

Is there another config dir? I did find `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.dpkg-new` , but this does not have a symlink in the sites-enabled dir.

Any help is welcome before I get crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/www/html/` is the default for `DocumentRoot` that Apache uses if no  `DocumentRoot` is configured.

Comment: Seems a reasonable explanation. So perhaps I should restate my problem: why does a config file (symlink) in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled not work, and do I still see /var/www/html/index.html served? I added another one in sites-available, and now everything works fine. The first one is with a virtual server, and the second one provides config for the default server. I will look into the virtual server config. For now, your answer has helped me, so I will gladly accept it.